# A() = A() - why does it compile?

Tags: c++

```
class A {};

int main() {
 A() = A();
 return 0; 
}
```

Why does this code compile? Shouldn't be there some error that on the left side of assignment operator should be placed lvalue? Is A() lvalue? g++ 4.7 version

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For built-in types, you'd be correct: the built-in assignment operator requires a modifiable *lvalue* on the left hand side.

However, this is not using the built-in operator, but the overload that's implicitly declared by the class. This is a member function, equivalent to

```
A().operator=(A());
```

and member functions can be called on *rvalues*.

Comment: isn't it copy initialization?

Comment: @Named its calling `operator=` on A

Comment: @Named: No, it's assignment not initialisation.

Comment: It could also be that `A::operator()` returns a reference that an "A" object can be assigned to...

Comment: @paul23: That's true (assuming you mean `operator=` not `operator()`), but doesn't have much to do with the question. The example doesn't do anything with the assignment's result.

Comment: @paul23 `A()` doesn't call `operator()`, it constructs an object of type `A`.

Comment: It can't be an initialisation because there's no declaration.

Comment: A constructor-function-call style cast is initialization.  Then the `=` is assignment.  This like of code has both.

Answer (score 32):

If you really want, you can make it not compile with C++11:

```
class A {
    template <typename T>
    void operator=(T&&) && = delete; // no op= for rvalues

    // generate other special members normally
    A() = default;
    A(A const&) = default;
    A(A&&) = default;
    ~A() = default;
    // op= only for lvalues
    A& operator=(A&&) & = default;
    A& operator=(A const&) & = default;
};

int main() {
 A() = A(); // error
 return 0; 
}
```

([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=dc9f5bc44173e9de01fa37ce4c40b879-c5813a17b8846a2b081300f6b124dac9))

Note the `&` and `&&` (aka ref-qualifiers) at the end of the declarations of the various `operator=` forms. This makes those declarations be selected for lvalues and rvalues respectively. However, the rvalue version, when selected by overload resolution causes the program to be ill-formed because it is deleted.

The default generated operator=, however, does not have any ref-qualifier, meaning it can be called for both lvalues and rvalues; that's why the code in the question compiles, even though `A()` is an rvalue.

Answer (score 1):

C++ compiler provides all classes with a default constructor, that's what happening, with respect to your code, when you say 
A()=A();
it just invokes the constructor with a nameless object and the function returns reference to the constructed object (implicit). That's it...